# get all the proper namespaces and ingressroutes with the python k8's api client library

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress

I have the following command line below. It gives me the namespaces and ingressroutes names (see the Example below)

`kubectl --context mlf-eks-dev get --all-namespaces ingressroutes`

**Example**

```
NAMESPACE                       NAME                                                           AGE
aberdeentotalyes               aberdeentotalgeyes-yesgepi                                      98d
```

I"m trying to replicate the kubetl command line above through my python code, using the python client for kubernetes but I miss on the option, on how to get the ingressroutes.

```
#My python code
from kubernetes import client, config

# Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper utility
config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s" % (i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

The results are below

```
wwwpaulolo   ci-job-backup-2kt6f
wwwpaulolo   wwwpaulolo-maowordpress-7dddccf44b-ftpbq
wwwvhugo        ci-job-backup-dz5hs
wwwvhugo        wwwvhua-maowordpress-5f7bdfdccd-v7kcx
```

I have the namespaces but not the ingressroutes, as I don't know how can I get it.

Question is what is the option to have the ingressroutes, please?

Any helps are more than welcomed.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a careful reading of the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md) of the existing APIs for ingressroutes, I found none that can be used, all of them are still in beta as Ingressroutes is not a native components of Kubernetes.

I also asked on Slack's Kubernetes, on the Kubernetes client channel.

Alan C on Kubernetes's slack, gave me that answer:

> There's no class for ingressroutes. You can use the dynamic client to
> support arbitrary resource types ([see link](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/tree/fd322f70aa6c33782ab466afd4eaae271a27cbcb/dynamic))

My solution is to use the python library `subprocess` to run the `kubectl` command line.

Answer (score 0):

did you try CustomObjectsApi?

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
api = client.CustomObjectsApi()
dir(api) # check for list_cluster_custom_object 

#example below api will list all issuers in the cluster. 
#issuer is custom resource of cert-manager.io
api.list_cluster_custom_object(group="cert-manager.io",
version="v1",plural="issuers")
```